# How to uninstall Boost 1.55 with unix?

Tags: unix, boost, uninstallation

I just installed boost 1.55 onto my server with unix.
For some reason the installation had some errors and I would like to uninstall it
and try installing it again, but I can't manage to figure out how to uninstall the program.

Comment: It would help if you explain how you installed it: from the packages of your distribution? did you compiled it?

Comment: i downloaded version 1.55 and unpacked it. I entered the boost directory and prepared the build "./bootstrap.sh". I then built boost by writing "./bjam --prefix=<YOUR_BOOST_INSTALL_DIRECTORY> link=static runtime-link=static stage install".